# Print an array as a table

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Write a program that prints an associative array (key-value) to a table.

## Requirements

- Standard loopholes are forbidden
- Please include a link to an online interpreter and the byte count  in the answer
- Use [box drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character)  to draw the table.
- You can write both a full program or a function.
- Key or value can't contain multiline strings.
- Value/key can't be an array/associative array ( example: `["a"=>["a"=>"b"]] or  ["a"=>["a","b"]]` )

### Special cases

- If the programming language lacks of associative array , you can use a list of pairs. Example:  `[[key1,value1],[key2,value2]]`
- You can insert horizontal lines between successive pairs.
- An input array can't be empty

#### This is a code-golf, the answer with the shortest byte count wins!

## Challenge

Your code must draw a vertical table like in the example from a associative array . The key must be at left and value must be at right and them needs to be separed,you can choose how separe them. Every key-value pair must be in another row.
There must be only 2 columns for the keys and value.

## Example

Array(PHP):

`["a"=>"b","c"=>"d","d"=>"d"]`

Output:

```
┏━━━┓
┃a┃b┃
┃c┃d┃
┃d┃d┃
┗━━━┛
```

Comment: Thanks, please edit the post accordingly (we prefer not to have spec in comments). Also what are the rules regarding justification? (e.g `["abba"=>"1","b"=>"20"]`)

Comment: Can we use any normal box drawing characters instead of the heavy ones?

Comment: Can we use `┬` and `┴` when separating the columns?

Comment: @PurpleP there is no specification about justification

Comment: Maybe for next time, use [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/) to get all the questions answered before posting?

Comment: @Adám yes, i fixed my question

Comment: While I'm still waiting for an answer about the 3-way pieces, does the separators between names and values have to line up?

Comment: separators between key-values not necessary have to line up and yes, you can use 3 way pieces @Adám

Comment: @MicioInformatico "Value/key can't be an array" doesn't quite work, as "a list of pairs" is also an array, and, well, an "associative array" is obviously also an array.

Comment: I mean, you cant do this : ["a"=>["x"=>"b"],"c"=>["d"=>"b"]] ( in languages without associative array [[key1,[x=>value1]],[key2,[d=>value2]])

Comment: "An i**m**put array can't be empty"

Comment: @MicioInformatico OK, so we *can* take input as an N-row 2-column matrix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [TryAPL](https://tryapl.org), 1 [byte](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. As TryAPL has no associative arrays, this takes a list of pairs as argument.

```
↑
```

[Try APL!](https://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%u2191%20%u22C4%20f%20%28%27key1%27%20%27value1%27%29%20%28%27key2%27%20%27value2%27%29&run)

`↑` mix the list of pairs into a table

Comment: Question over, go home folks.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 1 byte

```
>
```

So… to take strings as input they need to be in boxes already, and to make them pairs I *think* they need to be put into a box again so that they can be treated separately. I'm not too sure about the second part.

Anyway, unboxing the whole thing gives the desired form.

I get a sense that this could be a 0 byte answer if we twist the format enough (or maybe less, since a 2d array of boxes seems to be the proper input format instead of my weird format), but I don't understand boxing all that well.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r//39qcka@gp2Gho2htZGmjoaNsbWJpiYXXFQ9MUndWj05RR0kp56alg7kZWRmqWtq/gcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 563 bytes

```php
<?php
    $t = ["a"=>"b","c"=>"d"];
    $k = $v = $i = $j = 0;
    foreach ($t as $a => $b){
        $k = (strlen($a) > $k ? strlen($a) : $k);
        $v = (strlen($b) > $v ? strlen($b) : $v);
    }
    echo "┏"; for(; $i++ < $k + $v + 3;) echo "━";
    echo "┓\n";
    foreach ($t as $a => $b){
        echo "|{$a} ";
        for($i = 0; $i < $k - strlen($a); $i++) echo " ";
        echo "| {$b}";
        for($i = 0; $i < $v - strlen($b); $i++) echo " ";
        echo "|\n";
    }
    echo "┗"; for(; $j++ < $k + $v + 3;) echo "━";
    echo "┛";
?>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZA7DsIwDIZ3TmFZGVoVJCQ2QtuDAENSispDpQKUpXTgBAwgMXA7LlLiBNqw8MhgJXa@379dZEVdj@IiKzqgD9tDCGMUGEYosYsJXWY45ba60lWmKCwoLHXo29J8s01FkoGnFcQOmIAwAib90lQb2Nvtt@s095jwIaJUDE5mqDM@bwnlEtIQyiGkIdSTqExMk2wDeL@ckJMnj2urQQAj6hUQHsCA@823I/I37DzJ8deBLHMomagAW9fU1aynT71t554zpXX0suCST0Eomaw@CipHUH4XbGZ6X9G1XdHyjxXd9DuO6voB)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 62 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞υ×━⌈ＥθＬ§κι⟦⪫┏┓⪫υ┳⟧Ｅθ⪫┃┃⪫Ｅι◨λＬ§υμ┃⪫┗┛⪫υ┻
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw0hTIaC0OEOjVEchJDM3tVhD6dGURiUdBd/Eiszc0lwN38QCjUIdBZ/UvPSSDA3HEs@8lNQKjWwdhUxNMLDmCijKzCvRiPbKz8wDae5/NGUyUD@YCzQUKLJZSVMzFq4QaiBMeTMQwZSDpDJ1FAISU4Iy0zNKNHIw7AUamAuyFWxusxKyA2AGTn80ZTaq/btB6qz//4@OjlZKVNJRSlKK1YlWSgayUpRiY2P/65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Charcoal's code page doesn't include box-drawing characters so they cost 3 bytes but the code uses them instead of their three-byte encoding because it looks nicer. Takes input as an array of tuples as Charcoal doesn't have an iterable dictionary. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²⊞υ×━⌈ＥθＬ§κι
```

Find the length of the longest key and value and repeat `━` according to that length.

```
⟦⪫┏┓⪫υ┳⟧
```

Embed the `━`s in `┏┳┓`.

```
Ｅθ⪫┃┃⪫Ｅι◨λＬ§υμ┃
```

For each tuple, pad the strings to the length of the `━`s and wrap them with `┃`s.

```
⪫┗┛⪫υ┻
```

Embed the `━`s in `┗┻┛`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>189</s> <s>172</s> <s>168</s> <s>173</s> 169 bytes

```python
def f(d):t=d.items();a,b=map(lambda*l:max(map(len,l)),*t);c='─'*a,'─'*b;print("┌%s┬%s┐"%c,*[f"│{k:{a}}│{v:{b}}│"for k,v in t],"└%s┴%s┘"%c,sep="\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYsxCoMwGIWvEn4QEwldukVykrbDH5NQUaNoEIsIpXOHDg49RMeeyItYY5f3Pj7ea27@WrvjumpjiaWaCS/1Ifem6ihLkStZYUNLrJTGpBQVDnQXxvGSMZ54lmYyXuZ7nCD/t0qbNneewjI/o26ZPyFeEGU8OdlNPsZCjDhNgXoxqp3A1i0peE9yR/yFb7M53L4h3uHbmUbC2QFbLR0BEQQo4ASyDbQOhLscYGLrDw)